# standardizing differently formatted varchar field to date in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I know similar questions have been asked in the past, but they still haven't given me a proper solution for my case.

I have a database table (third party) that has a `varchar` column for a `datetime` value.

It contains dates in the following formats.

```
  11181980 
  8 18 1960 
  10/01/1960 
  04-12-1953 
  041371 
  7/29/44
  Empty String 
  NULL
```

When I select this column, I want to bring the date in a standard format (say `mm/dd/yyyy`) when available or NULL.

I can only think of a function to do this, but I don't want to do a UDF as I need to make sure it does not error out while trying to convert. There is no try/catch in UDF. I could do a CLR function to make use of more powerful .net features though I would like to avoid it.

Is there any other better way to handle this conversion in SQL Server? Also how should I go about doing this conversion if possible in SQL.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot do a `BEGIN TRY ... END TRY ... BEGIN CATCH ... END CATCH` statement in a UDF?

Comment: No, you cannot, but thats not the point of the question. I'm mainly looking to see if there is any other way to handle this in SQL than going to .net functions.

Comment: What I'm saying is you don't need to use a CLR to get error handling.  You can do it in a Stored Proc or a SQL UDF.

Comment: With data like that, you will need error handling unless you can be sure you build in a case for each and every different style of data present in the field.

Comment: You just need this format when you select the data, but you don't want to fix it?

Comment: Thats correct. I won't be able to fix this data as it is coming from some old system and I have to use their tables directly. 'This is the fix' :)

Comment: And is /44 supposed to be interpreted as 1944 or 2044?

Comment: define each different "format" that exists, and how to identity and handle it. then just use `CASE` and `WHEN` for each variation to push them into a char(8) `yyyymmdd` format. store those char(8) values or wrap this in another `CASE WHEN isdate()=1...` and cast/convert to datetime

Comment: Ha. Thats a good one. It is definitely not the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the set of potential formats you've described:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(y VARCHAR(32))

INSERT @x VALUES
('11181980'),
('8 18 1960'),
('10/01/1960'),
('04-12-1953'), 
('041371'),
('7/29/44'),
(''), 
(NULL);

SET DATEFORMAT MDY;

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN y LIKE '%/%' THEN y
 WHEN LEN(RTRIM(y)) = 0 THEN NULL
 WHEN LEN(RTRIM(y)) IN (6,8) AND ISNUMERIC(y) = 1 THEN
 STUFF(STUFF(y,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/') END)
FROM (SELECT y = REPLACE(REPLACE(y, ' ', '/'), '-', '/') FROM @x) AS x;
```

This will interpret `7/29/44` as `2044`, not `1944`, based on server settings. To make sure all dates are in the past, you could do:

```
SELECT y = DATEADD(YEAR, CASE WHEN y > GETDATE() THEN -100 ELSE 0 END, y) 
FROM
(
  SELECT y = CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN y LIKE '%/%' THEN y
   WHEN LEN(RTRIM(y)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE
   STUFF(STUFF(y, 3, 0, '/'),6, 0, '/') END)
  FROM (SELECT y = REPLACE(REPLACE(y, ' ', '/'), '-', '/') FROM @x) AS x
) AS z;
```

This also depends on there being no garbage data that can't be massaged into a date. What kind of system enters this kind of inconsistent nonsense anyway?

In SQL Server 2012 you will be able to use [TRY_PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) or [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) but with that mess of formats you're still going to have to do some massaging to get meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the database but cannot change it, I would run a stored procedure that sanitizes all values to ONE common format and make sure that only entries in that format can be inserted/updated. If you can't control the CRUD operations, I would just fetch the "dates" as is and perform the conversion to a `DateTime` in your BL layer.

Perhaps not an answer to your question but personally I like all queries as simple as possible by keeping conversion and other logic outside the database.

Comment: Unfortunately that data is populated by a third party and I cannot update it. Also I need that data in the database, from other procedures, not from code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do the following:

1. Find whoever designed that table and shoot them
2. Write a CLR function to parse the value to a date, probably using regex pattern matching
3. Create a view that returns all of the same columns, but your function result instead of the varchar field

To be honest that data looks like rubbish, I doubt you could rely on it at all. It's possible there are values such as:

- 11190
- 1111990

Should these be 1990-11-01 or 1990-01-11? I think the CLR function will get you the most data in the most stable manner.

Comment: Ok, maybe don't actually shoot them.  Just sayin'.  You never know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, to this 3-year old question. I did not have any spaces in mine, but you can use this as the basis and use the *replace* function to strip those out when you evaluate. Here you go, Internet. Thanks for all the help the last 10 years. This is rather specific to SQL data import export but will hopefully help someone who is otherwise stuck in manual ETL mode.

```
    CASE    WHEN DOB LIKE '__/__/____'  THEN [DOB]                              -- PROPER FORMAT
    WHEN DOB LIKE '_/__/____'   THEN '0'+ [DOB]                         -- NEED TO ADD A ZERO TO THE MONTH
    WHEN DOB LIKE '__/_/____'   THEN  LEFT(DOB,3)+'0'+RIGHT(DOB,6)      -- NEED TO ADD A ZERO TO THE DAY
    WHEN DOB LIKE '_/_/____'    THEN '0'+LEFT(DOB,2)+'0'+RIGHT(DOB,6)   -- NEED TO ADD A ZERO TO THE MONTH AND DAY
    WHEN LEN(DOB)=8 AND DOB BETWEEN '1900' AND '2016' THEN LEFT(RIGHT(DOB,4),2) + '/' + RIGHT(DOB,2) +'/'+ LEFT(DOB,4)
    WHEN LEN(DOB)=8 AND DOB BETWEEN '01011900' AND '12312016' AND DOB NOT LIKE '%/%' THEN LEFT(DOB,2) + '/' + RIGHT(LEFT(DOB,4),2) +'/'+ RIGHT(DOB,4)
    WHEN DOB LIKE '__/__/__'     -- CONVERT FROM MM/DD/YY (ADD TWO DIGIT YEAR PREFIX)
        THEN    CASE    WHEN RIGHT(replace(dob,'/',''),2) > RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2) --WHEN 2-DIGIT YEAR IS WITHIN 100 YEARS AGO USE 19
                            THEN LEFT(DOB,2)+'/'+LEFT(RIGHT(replace(dob,'/',''),4),2)+'/19'+RIGHT(replace(dob,'/',''),2) 
                        WHEN RIGHT(DOB,2) < RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2) --WHEN 2-DIGIT YEAR IS MORE THAN 100 YEARS AGO USE 20
                            THEN LEFT(DOB,2)+'/'+LEFT(RIGHT(replace(dob,'/',''),4),2)+'/20'+RIGHT(replace(dob,'/',''),2) 
                ELSE NULL END
```

ELSE NULL END AS [DOB_CONVERTER]

As Max Vernon points out, you must account for every pattern to match and fix. Error handling would be great to get this automated. Until then look over the data once it is cleaned, load to a temp table and look for baddies using similar like patterns (WHERE NULL to find non pattern matching) (WHERE RIGHT(LEFT(REPLACE([DOB],'/',''),4),2) > 31

Pattern searches was a helpful site at microsoft.com
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx