# Simple way to standardize varchar "dates" to single date format in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting

I have a table in a postgres database with a varchar date column that mixes MM/DD/YY with MM/DD/YYYY data formats. For example:

```
1/17/89
1/28/2018
12/30/2006
10/1/17
```

I'd like all of the dates to follow a MM/DD/YYYY format:

```
1/17/1989
1/28/2018
12/30/2006
10/1/2017
```

I'm aware it's not a best practice for dates to be in a varchar field, but I did not create this table and I cannot change the data type. Is it possible to use SQL to make this kind of change to my table?

I'm aware of similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200367/standardizing-differently-formatted-varchar-field-to-date-in-sql-server), but this seems a bit more than what I'm looking for, and I can't seem to extract an answer from it that's appropriate for my issue.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329167/varchar-values-to-date-format) seems closer to what I'm looking for, but again, I can't seem to implement the answer. How would it know which table and field to make changes to? (I'm a total SQL noob if you can't tell).

Comment: No.  You should want all of them to be stored using the proper data type, `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this code:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(my_date,'MM/DD/YY')::TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as new_varchar_date FROM my_table;

-- for update the actual values 
UPDATE my_table SET my_date = to_char(to_date(my_date,'MM/DD/YY')::TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

At first you need to convert the `varchar` to `date`, then to `timestamp` and then to `varchar` again.

Result should look like:

```
01/17/1989
01/28/2018
12/30/2006
10/01/2017
```

Comment: Hmm... I got some strange output from that: 0018-09-20, 2006-03-25, etc...

Comment: That's a lot better, and something I can work with now, but I would have expected 09/20/2018 and 10/18/2017, for example, but instead I'm getting 2018-09-20 and 2017-10-18. Why is that? Also, how do you make the actual change to the table? This seems to just produce a "result" without making any actual changes to the column values.

Comment: I think it's also changing the data type to a date type and not keeping it a varchar type

Comment: Yes! It does! Thank you so much!